# How to get rows containing ONLY certain strings?

Tags: mysql

I have these words in my `words` table in a MySQL db:

```
kaki

koku

kao

kakeru
```

How can I get all rows that contains ONLY 'ka','ki','ku','ke','ko'?

I want to get `kaki` and `koku` but not `kao` and `kakeru`, because although `kao` contains `ka`, it also has `o`, and although `kakeru` contains `ka` and `ke` it also contains `ru`.

I have tried:

```
select *
from words
where (
    word like '%ka%'
    or word like '%ki%'
    or word like '%ku%'
    or word like '%ke%'
    or word like '%ko%'
    );
```

but I don't get the result that I want.

EDIT: I can't comment, but yes I want to break it into 2 syllables.

Comment: Do you always want to break your words up into syllables two letters long?

Comment: Is this Hawaiian or Japanese? Are there any 1-letter syllables or 3-or-more-letter syllables? (I see you have `o` as a syllable...)

Comment: To the OP (and @OblivionCoder) : You can always comment in your own questions. But you need to first merge your accounts. It seems you posted the question from an unregistered account. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try some `REPLACE()` tricks:

```
SELECT *
FROM #words
WHERE REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
    word
    ,'ka','')
    ,'ke','')
    ,'ki','')
    ,'ko','')
    ,'ku','')
    = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE word REGEXP "^(k[aeiou])+$"
```

will check for a pair of (k+vowel) letter pairs.

- `k` matches just `k`.
- `[aeiou]` matches any of the letters in the brackets.
- `^` and `$` "anchor" both ends -- no other text on either end
- `()+` says "one or more"

Comment: The query gets kakeru.

Comment: @OblivionCoder -- sometimes I am blind to the question.  See if the changes I just made match the requirements.